# When resizing window, divs will not stay put. Help me out?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Okay so usually I can fix this myself but I'm stuck. I have been trying and trying and I just can't get my website to stay normal when I am resizing the browser window. I added a div that holds everything inside it and named it "bodycontainer". Here's my website: http://avosinc.com/new/

Here's the style I have for it:

```
#bodycontainer {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

And still, it doesn't want to stay put.
Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

your using `px` they are not responsive just static.. try using `%` as that will scale down with it.

```
#bodycontainer {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: just looked at your website CSS this one line wont fix it your css is all over the place you built it non responsive with px and static css styles.. you should really look into css frameworks like foundation and bootstrap when building these sites. @RubenRyapolov

Comment: How can I fix this? I used a base bare template and built everything up. Is this why?

Comment: what the whole website.. rebuild your css (well some of it) and use media queries to make it responsive.. i would highly recommend using one of the frameworks i suggested it allows the website to be easily maintained. But a little change to this one class wont make the whole page responsive @RubenRyapolov

Comment: What can I do to fix this without having to change the entire site? I'm not sure I understand what you mean...